# How to implement a uniform random walk on a simplex?

Tags: markov-chain-montecarlo, random-walk

I am looking for an uniform random walk algorithm on a simplex for MCMC purposes. Hence the process should on average spent the same time in any given area. I want this to be my proposal algorithm. The Dirichlet distribution has all sorts of problems at proposing samples near the boundaries. This is well documented.

The only algorithm I could find was https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User%3aSkinnerd/Simplex_Point_Picking. It looks like the algorithm will "struggle" to escape when near the boundary of the simplex i.e for values close to zero xnew = xold*random_number. Am I correct in that this algorithm is not a random walk on a simplex? or am I missing something? I implemented the algorithm and as I thought too many  samples are at the boundary of the simplex.

[image: The MCMC samples from the linked algorithm.]

Comment: I wouldn't expect a random walk on a simplex to be uniform; what's the basis on which you say that there's too many near the boundary? How do you know what the behavior of a random walk on the simplex should look like near the boundary?

Comment: Your random walk must be uniform, right? If so, I think you should add this point in your question.

Comment: The link describes how to perform a uniform random walk. I should have made it clearer that I wanted a uniform random walk. Edited.

Comment: ^ the algorithm described in the linked Wikipedia user's page is erroneous, as explained in my answer to the aforementioned question

Comment: @JuhoKokkala I did try your suggestion using the correct Metropolis Hastings algorithm, but then the samples are even less uniform.

Comment: Despite the title, https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/103105/simplex-random-walk does not seem to address this question at all.  I have therefore reopened this thread.

Answer (score 6):

I understand your simplex to be the specific subset

$$\Delta^d = \{(x_1,x_2,\ldots, x_d)\mid 0 \le x_1 \le x_2 \le \cdots \le x_d \le 1\} \subset \mathbb{R}^d.$$

(If not, a linear map onto any other $d$-dimensional simplex will have constant Jacobean and therefore will convert any uniform distribution on this simplex to a uniform distribution on the target.)

Start anywhere at $\mathbf{x}^{(0)}\in\mathbb{R}^d$.  Generate independent, identically distributed increments $\mathbf{h}^{(i)} \in \mathbb{R}^d$, $i=1, 2, \ldots, n$, according to your random walk.  Compute their cumulative sums

$$\mathbf{x}^{(i)} = \mathbf{x}^{(i-1)} + \mathbf{h}^{(i)}$$

for $i=1, 2, \ldots, n$.

Consider the reflections through all hyperplanes that are parallel to the coordinate planes and situated at integral distances from them.  These generate a [reflection group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_group) $H$ that includes translations by vectors all of whose coordinates are integral multiples of $2$.  A [fundamental domain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_domain) for $H$ is the unit cube

$$I^d = \{(x_1, \ldots, x_d)\mid 0 \le x_i \lt 1, i=1, 2, \ldots, d\}.$$

Replacing each $\mathbf{x}^{(i)}$ by its unique representative $\mathbf{y}^{(i)}$ in $I^d$ produces a random walk on $I^d$ that asymptotically is uniform.  (Indeed, when the standard deviation of the coordinate increments is not too small compared to $1$, the uniformity is very rapidly achieved: see method (8) at https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/117711/919.)

[image: Figure showing scatterplot matrix of y for d=4]

*Here is a scatterplot matrix of the components of $\mathbb{y}$ for $d=4$, $n=10^4$. Increments were drawn from a Normal distribution with standard deviation $d$.*

This random walk projects to a uniform walk on the simplex $\Delta^d$ simply by sorting each vector $\mathbb{y}^{(i)}$.  Sorting can be viewed as including $H$ in a larger reflection group $G$ whose generators also contain all permutations of the coordinates.

[image: Figure showing scatterplot matrix of z]

*The projections onto planes do not look uniform--they shouldn't be.*

Please note that the individual coordinates cannot be uniform or even identically distributed and that their increments will not be identically distributed either.

[image: Histograms of z coordinates]

*These are histograms of individual coordinates ($z_1$ through $z_4$ are shown left to right).*

[image: Histograms of increments of z]

*These are histograms of the increments of the individual coordinates.  Note how the middle histograms differ from the outer ones.*

For the purpose of generating proposals in an MCMC algorithm, you may generate the original walk $\mathbf{x}^{(i)}$ sequentially: the new proposal is its reduction modulo $G$.

---

The description of the group $G$ in terms of two sets of reflections allows realizations of these walks to be efficiently generated: beginning with a walk in $\mathbb{R}^d$, reduce the coordinates modulo $H$ and then reduce the results by sorting the coordinates.  To reduce coordinates modulo $H$, exploit the fact that $H$ contains all the translations by multiples of $2$: reduce all coordinates modulo $2$, and then apply the reflection

$$u \to 2-u$$

for any coordinate value $1\le u \lt 2$.  Finally, sort the coordinates to obtain the corresponding point in the simplex.

Here is working `R` code to illustrate.

```R
#
# Uniform random walk on the simplex 0 <= x[1] <= ... <= x[d] <= 1,
#
d <- 4
n <- 1e4          # Number of points
sigma <- d        # SD of lengths Normal-component increments
start <- rep(0, d)
#
# Generate the walk.
#
dx <- matrix(rnorm(n*d, sd=sigma/sqrt(d)), nrow=n) # n X d matrix of increments
x <- apply(dx, 2, cumsum)                          # n X d matrix of raw values
y <- x %% 2
y <- apply(y, 2, function(u) ifelse(u >= 1, 2-u, u))
z <- t(apply(y, 1, sort))
#
# Display the walk `z` in various ways,
# first with scatterplot matrices of `y` and `z`.
#
colnames(y) <- paste("y", 1:d, sep=".")
colnames(z) <- paste("z", 1:d, sep=".")
pairs(y, cex=1/4, col="#00000020")
pairs(z, cex=1/4, col="#00000020")
#
# Histograms of `z` and its increments `dz`.
#
dz <- apply(z, 2, diff)
par(mfrow=c(1, d))
invisible(apply(z, 2, hist, freq=FALSE, breaks=30, xlab="z", main=""))
invisible(apply(dz, 2, hist, freq=FALSE, breaks=30, xlab="dz", main=""))
```

Comment: Thanks. I need $\sum_{i=1}^{d}x_i =1$; it is not clear to me that this is a constraint in your algorithm?

Comment: I appreciate your effort. I will implement this and have a look.

Comment: @whuber: brilliant!

Comment: Travis, my initial remarks address this constraint (assuming your $x_i$ are nonnegative).  The transformation from the simplex I use to the simplex you want is to take the successive differences of the coordinates.  This is a one-to-one area-preserving correspondence between the two.

Comment: Can you please show (by connecting the dots) the random walk?

Comment: There may be too many dots to make that effective.  Instead, I recommend varying the colors of the dots by their times in the walk. *E.g.*, replace the `col` option in the `pairs` commands by `col=hsv(1:n/(1.2*n), 1, 1, 0.5)`.  Early times are red, graduating through yellow, green cyan, blue, to purple at late times. Overlapping points are translucent. To see the effect better, set `n <- 1e3` at the outset (reducing the length) and `sigma <- d/sqrt(n)` (reducing the variance) and include the option `ylim=0:1` in `pairs` to show any empty regions that might appear.